# C# Event handlers are not available to another reference

Tags: c#, events, observablecollection

I have an example class. It has an ObservableCollection with an event handler attached.

```
class SomeItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();
    
    private SomeEventHandler(object Sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs E)
    {
        //do something
    }
    
    public SomeItem()
    {
        this.Things.CollectionChanged += SomeEventHandler;
    }
}
```

I'm executing the following code:

```
SomeItem Instance = new SomeItem();

Instance.Things.Add(new Thing()); // SomeEventHandler executed;

SomeItem AnotherReference = Instance;

AnotherReference.Things.Add(new Thing()); // SomeEventHandler NOT executed
```

Why the event handler not being executed if collection is accessed from **AnotherReference**?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem. This code works as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            SomeItem Instance = new SomeItem();
          
            Instance.Things.Add(new Thing()); // SomeEventHandler executed;
            
            SomeItem AnotherReference = Instance;
            
            AnotherReference.Things.Add(new Thing()); // SomeEventHandler ALSO executed
        }
    }

    class Thing { 
    }

    class SomeItem
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();

        private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from SomeEventHandler");
        }

        public SomeItem() {
            this.Things.CollectionChanged += SomeEventHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Hello from SomeEventHandler
Hello from SomeEventHandler
Press any key to continue.
```